# Дефис/раздельно

Tags: орфография, грамматика

"Реально()выполненный", "прямо()противоположный" — эти сочетания пишут без дефиса?

Answer (score 1):

Хочу уточнить, что они пишутся не только без дефиса, но и раздельно. А то не очевидно, что именно это считал другим вариантом Roman. Не факт, что и из ответа про наречия ему это очевидно.

Answer (score 0):

### Да, без дефиса.

Answer (score 0):

Пишутся без дефиса. "Реально" и "прямо" в данном случае наречия.